# Add onblur event to ASP.Net MVC's Html.TextBox

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper

What's the correct syntax for an HTML helper (in MVC2) to define an onblur handler where the textbox is generated with code like:

```
<%=Html.TextBox(
    "ChooseOptions.AddCount" + order.ID,
    (order.Count > 0) ?  AddCount.ToString() : "",
    new { @class = "{number: true}  small-input" }
)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Add the `onblur` to htmlattributes**

```
<%=Html.TextBox(
    "ChooseOptions.AddCount" + order.ID,
    (order.Count > 0) ?  AddCount.ToString() : "",
    new { @class = "{number: true}  small-input", onblur = "alert('fired')" }
) %>
```

**Or a better way add it with jQuery**

```
$('#ChooseOptions_AddCount' + id).onblur(function() { alert('fired'); });
```

Comment: The page uses jQuery but I haven't parsed the model values over to it in any overt way. In order to use the jQuery suggestion i'd have to do some sort of <script> jqValue = <%=serverSideValue%> </script>, right. Things are quite _that magical yet, are they?

Comment: It should be "blur" not "onblur"    $('#ChooseOptions_AddCount' + id).blur(function() { alert('fired'); });

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to submit a solution which allows you to reuse your function code, if you want. You can define the function elsewhere, and then call it from the HTML element.

Somewhere in the myView.cshtml file (maybe at the top of the  body  tags) you can define a script and define myFunc inside, like this:

```
<script>
    function myFunc() {
        alert('fired');
    }
</script>
```

Then call it from the HTML element, like this:

```
<%=Html.TextBox(
    "ChooseOptions.AddCount" + order.ID,
    (order.Count > 0) ?  AddCount.ToString() : "",
    new { @class = "{number: true}  small-input", onblur = "myFunc()" }
) %>
```

Or, if you're happy to use a HTML helper to define your textbox, you can do

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ChooseOptions.AddCount,
    (order.Count > 0) ?  AddCount.ToString() : "",
    new { @class = "{number: true}  small-input", onblur = "myFunc()" }
)
```